# "Bildet sich ein Sturm" or "Formt sich ein Sturm"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

How do you say "a storm forms in the ocean" in German?

> 1. Der Sturm formt sich über dem Ozean.
> 2. Der Sturm bildet sich über dem Ozean.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is

> Der Sturm *braute sich* über dem Ozean *zusammen*.

This translation is especially used in literary text types.

*zusammenbrauen* describes the emergence of a potentially *threatening* situation, in this case a storm. *zusammenbrauen* can also be used for *mixing different liquids*.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct, but *bildet* is the use regarded as both more accurate and the phrase used in most of my meteorology books.

Answer (score 3):

Also heard of is

> Ein Sturm kommt/zieht über dem Ozean auf.

Answer (score 3):

The most basic and neutral one for a storm would be

> Der Sturm entsteht...

*Bilden* works too, but *entstehen* is much more common ([bilden](https://www.google.de/search?q=der%20strum%20entstand&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=der%20strum%20entstand&aqs=chrome..69i57.4975j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=%22der%20sturm%20bildet%20sich%22), [enstehen](https://www.google.de/search?q=der%20strum%20entstand&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=der%20strum%20entstand&aqs=chrome..69i57.4975j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=%22der%20sturm%20entsteht%22) on Google). Also, the noun would definitely be

> Die Entstehung des Sturms

and not *die Bildung*.

Any other choice (the ones suggested in the other answers) adds color.